# How to make child component use parent component style

Tags: angular

How can I make the `app-dropdown-select` use the style of component A?

**component A:**

This can be use to make the parent use child component's style:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Is there something like this to make parent style override the child style?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the encapsulation with the `::ng-deep` piercing CSS combinator ([see docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)) in the parent (add `!important` if needed) but it is deprecated because each component must remain modular and autonomous, without causing conflicts between them.

You should prefer using [SASS variables](https://netbasal.com/angular-cli-and-global-sass-variables-a1b92d8ca9b7) and CSS import.